# Pitfalls of using SQL transactions vs .NET transactions

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I've been playing around with using transaction in SQL server and in C#.  Consider a store procedure which inserts a row into a three column table

```
alter proc spInsertItem
 @itemId int
,@itemDescription varchar(50)
,@itemCost decimal
as
begin
    if(@itemCost < 0)
        begin
            raiserror('cost cannot be less than 0',16,1)
        end

    else
        begin
            begin try
                begin tran
                    insert into Items(itemid, [description],itemCost)
                    values (@itemid, @itemdescription,@itemCost)
                commit tran
            end try
        begin catch
            rollback tran
                select   ERROR_LINE()as errorLine
                        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() as errorMessage
                        ,ERROR_STATE() as errorState
                        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() as errorProcedure
                        ,ERROR_NUMBER() as errorNumber
        end catch
    end
end
```

vs

```
create proc spInsertItem2
 @itemid int
,@itemDescription varchar(50)
,@itemCost decimal
as
begin
insert into Items(ItemId,[Description],ItemCost)
values (@itemid, @itemDescription,@itemCost)
end
```

In the first example the user is notified that they are unable to enter in an item cost less than 0, and the rest is pretty self explanatory.  This got me to thinking, if you're going to want to disallow a certain values you should need a check constraint, so I added the following constraint

```
alter table items
add constraint chkItemCost 
check (ItemCost > 0)
```

Now the two stored procedures function the same in code, and the SQL is much shorter and in my opinion, easier to read in the second, shorter version.  Granted, this is a very rudimentary example, but to me it seems that if you see the `try/catch` in code when you call the stored procedure, you can be sure of the database not being put in an inconsistent state.  So, what am I missing that I shouldn't rely on C# to create transactions?

Comment: FYI - edited your title because you really meant ".NET Transactions"

Comment: The real use case is for longer procedures, especially if you need to use explicit transactions (i.e. you delete records from a table and then insert new data) - you want the try/catch to abort the procedure and then add a rollback in the catch.

Comment: @JNK So for smaller 'everyday' type applications, i.e. typical updates, inserts, deletes it probably isn't necessary to write the transactions in SQL?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie it depends on if you ever plan to call those procs from anything besides your .NET code.  If you DO then I think the transactions should be in the SQL, but I'm a SQL developer so I'm biased

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a design decision; where the logic of application housed. If you decide upon concentrating your business logic in the application code, for each atomic application logic which involves multiple trips to the database, you need to wrap that logic using transaction in C#.

Whereas, if you house business logic in the database with the help of SPs, you do not need transaction in C#.

A common scenario is:

1. You create one or more records in the database.
2. You do some post processing on this data in C#.
3. You update another table with the data you just processed .

The requirement is that if step 2 or 3 fails, step 1 (created records) should be rolled back. For this you need transactions. You may argue that you can put all the three steps in an SP and wrap it with a transaction; it should be possible and is generally a matter of preference of where you put your application logic.